# Zend 3 + Doctrine 2 Create tables?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have been wondering around articles on google trying to "find a way" to create tables using doctrine. I need to create "temporary tables" because the project I am working on will have a lot of "temp statistics" and I do not need to have all the information, just a "total" at some point. Anyway MYSQL "temporary" tables would just be the "solution".

However, I cannot find a single piece of information where it shows you how to create tables with Doctrine.

I understand that Doctrine needs the tables to be created and the entities, but there must be a way to create tables "on-the-fly", or a way to run raw queries.

Here's a piece of code I have tried, and of course it failed:

```
$schema= new \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema();

        //if (!$schema->tablesExist('post'))
        //{
            $table= new \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table('post');
            $table->addColumn('id', 'integer', ['autoincrement'=>true]);
            $table->addColumn('title', 'text', ['notnull'=>true]);
            $table->addColumn('content', 'text', ['notnull'=>true]);
            $table->addColumn('status', 'integer', ['notnull'=>true]);
            $table->addColumn('date_created', 'datetime', ['notnull'=>true]);
            $table->setPrimaryKey(['id']);
            $table->addOption('engine' , 'InnoDB');

            $schema->createTable($table); // save to DB
        //}
```

Can someone please clarify to me if tables can or cannot be created with Doctrine ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you have written is called a migration, and if the migrations are installed and configured properly, can be executed using the command:

```
php public/index.php migrations:migrate
```

If you wish to create a table without a migrations, simply create an entity first, configure the mappings (using the annotations or any other type of your choice) and force create the schema using:

```
php public/index.php doctrine:schema:update --force
```

If you wish to run raw queries you can:

```
$this->entityManager->getConnection()->executeQuery('SQL Query', $optionalParams);
```

Comment: I cannot use the console, at all. I need to create tables "on-the-fly" for example: table_session_12345, table_session_453545, if that makes sense... so I don't know how I could create the entities before hand.

Comment: Doctrine is about mapping PHP objects to SQL tables, you can't have some random tables without entities. Your case seems very weird to me. You can always run RAW queries though

Comment: It is indeed weird, because this "part" of the project has a lot of statistics and then after some time it needs an "overall". Writing to the "statistics" table all the time is not a good idea, as it will grow very fast, in a very short time...

Comment: Then you have chosen wrong tools and this is a case where Doctrine should not be used at all. Rather raw SQL queries hidden behind a database adapter.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but "$this->entityManager->getConnection()->executeQuery" actually does the job :) I can run any query I want to. Many thanks for this, excellent answer!

Comment: Please upvote the answer too if you found it helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: One small issue, I see the query sometimes runs and sometimes not, and $this->entityManager->getConnection()->executeQuery('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE csv_import(id INT,entitiy_id INT,attribute_id INT,VALUE TEXT)ENGINE MyISAM'); doesn't do anything... any suggestions for a good adapter next to doctrine if possible ?

Comment: This command is a simple wrapper over the PDO instance. On any error an exception is thrown. Make sure your user has sufficient rights to execute this kinds of queries.